# How to insert property in Autodetected Component in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using @Service annotation of spring, so that my class should be autodetected by spring and made available for autowiring.But in my class, I need a property 'sqlmap'.If I had been using way of creating beans instead of auto-detection, I would have supplied that property using property tag in that bean..
So, is there any way I can inject my property in my class?Because unless that property is made available, spring will not be able to create bean of that class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@Service` class can "pull" a bean into a property using `@Resource`, e.g.

```
@Service
public class MyService {

   @Resource (name="sqlMapClient")
   private SqlMapClient sqlMapClient;
}
```

An alternative to `@Resource` is `@Autowired`, which will automatically select the target by type:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

   @Autowired
   private SqlMapClient sqlMapClient;
}
```

Try both, see which works best for you.

Comment: Hey, actually that name is sqlMapClient and when I define it as bean in my config file,it's type is org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean...

Comment: I tried @Autowired ..but got the error as 'property sqlMapClient is required',which means it was unable to autowire it

Comment: And when I tried @Resource, it gave error as 'Bean named 'sqlMapClient' must be of type [org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean], but was actually of type [com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl]'....Can u pls explain why this is happening?

Comment: @Sumit: See edit; if the bean type is `SqlMapClientFactoryBean`, then the property type should be `SqlMapClient`.